# Double-slit experiment with entangled particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Based on this [Double double-slit experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103359/double-double-slit-experiment) question, I have a setup that differs slightly:

[screen 1] [double slit 1] [entangled generator] [enough space] [double slit 2] [screen 2]

The entangled generator produces a pair of entangled particles P1 and P2.
P2 reaches the double slit 2 after P1 reaches screen 1 - so the distance between double slit 1 <-> entangled generator is smaller than between double slit 2 <-> entangled generator.
On screen 1 I expect to see interference pattern.

What could we expect to see on screen 2?
Edit: and what can be expected if the P1 reaches screen 1 after P2 reaches the double slit but before the screen 2?

Thank you

Comment: This is explored here  https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4943 at the end, also here https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-68181-1.pdf?origin=ppub

Comment: How are the two particles entangled if not correlated?How can the two particles be correlated if one reaches the screen before the other? What do these two particles even have in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see interference on screen 2 (and on screen 1). In your version you have NO coincident detection circuit and NO detectors/beam splitters that would provide paths for which way or non-which way .....  so you will always have an undisturbed "wave function" from the moment the first photon is created, sees the first slits, then splits and then seen at the screens .... these photons see the full affects of the slits and therefore make the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Particles can be *entangled* in many ways. If the spins of the two particles are entangled, then the experiment will be the same as if they were not, since we are not measuring the spin at all.